# Is there any way to detect an application crash and then launch it again in Android?

Tags: android, crash

I have an APP_A. It will crash when it actived for a long time. I try to find out the resolution to solve the problem but still stuck in it. So I want to try a short term solution that launch APP_B in backgroud then detect the status of APP_A. If it crash, then APP_B will launch it again.

Is there any way to detect if APP_A crash or not?

Comment: You can track a crash by using Crashlytics, but cannot launch bu code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the system force stops your application, the entire process is simply killed. There is no callback made to inform you that this has happened but there is workaround and  you can try:
https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-auto-restart-an-android-application-after-a-crash-or-a-force-close-error-1a361677c0ce

Comment: The Medium link is not working. What steps should I take?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventbus library (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to detect your crash on every situation in your apps and send mail to your mail ID to detect the crash report by using this library (https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to get the crash through FABRIC and check the logs in ANDROID STUDIO by analysing stack trace.
ANDROID STUDIO--> ANALYSE-->ANALYSE STACKTRACE